# Multiple network interfaces do transfer data

Tags: networking

I have a virtualization server with 4 network interfaces and connected it to a SAN. There are few virtual machines which writes data to the SAN.

I want to connect to the SAN with multiple interfaces to speed up the network.

Is it possible to send data on multiple interfaces? How can I configure it?

Computers are connected to san through switch.
SAN: Equallogic PS 4100 E
Switch: Dell Power Connect
Computer: Dell T610
OS: Centos 5
Virtualization: Kvm

NIC: 8

I am not sure about network card brand now.

Answer (score 0):

If both your SAN and you virtualization server support it then you can tie two or more network interfaces together into one virtual, faster interface.

Depending on your OS, switches and SAN this is usually called link aggregation or Ethernet trunking.

If you want a more detailed answer you will have to add more information to your post (edit it so it includes OS, network cards used, SAN model, number of NICs on the SAN, optionally used switched (brand and model), ... )